# Android Studio doesn't find JAVA_HOME if not run as administrator

Tags: java, android-studio, environment-variables

As the header states, Android Studio will complain about the `JAVA_HOME` variable not being found unless I run it as an administrator. When I run it as admin it will run perfectly/complain about the specific path I set for the `JAVA_HOME` variable (i.e. it can access the path and find the JAVA_HOME variable).

Of course I want to be able to run Android Studio without running it without having to elevate it as Administrator, and wonder if anyone have a clue how to solve this.

**Android Studio version: 0.8.14**
**OS: Windows 8.1**

Comment: Isn't this simply setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable for the non-admin user? Environment variables are set per user. On Windows 8.1, press the Windows key to bring up the Start page, type 'environment' to search and click on the Settings category. You'll see 'Edit environment variables for your account'.

Comment: The account where Android Studio runs itself isn't any problem since it is an administrator account.
I am the admin user, but ofc not all programs run in elevated mode, and that is the problem - programs not running in elevated mode (from this problem I have) seem to not be able to access environment variables, which I find wierd.